# AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper or AWSDynamoDB?

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, swift, amazon-dynamodb

The AWS documentation is seemingly endless, and different pages tell me different things. For example, one page tells me that AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper is the entry point to working with DynamoDB, while another tells me that AWSDynamoDB is the entry point to working with DynamoDB. Which class should I be using? Why?

EDIT: One user mentioned he didn't understand the question. To be more clear, I want to know, in general, what the difference is between using AWSDynamoDB and AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper as entry points to interfacing a DynamoDB.

Comment: You're going to need to provide a little more context than that. What are you trying to do? What code have you written so far? Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before continuing.

Comment: Edited the question so you can better understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doc links for both:

- [AWSDynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSDynamoDB.html)
- [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.html)

Since both can clearly read, write, query, and scan, you need to pick out the differences. It appears to me that the ObjectMapper class supports the concept of mapping an `AWSDynamoDBModel` to a DB vs. directly manipulating specific objects (as AWSDynamoDB does). Moreover, it appears that AWSDynamoDB also supports methods for managing tables directly.

I would speculate that AWSDynamoDB is designed for managing data where the schema is pre-defined on the DB, and AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper is designed for managing data where the schema is defined by the client.

All of this speculation aside though, the most important bit you can glean from the documentation is:

> Instead of making the requests to the low-level DynamoDB API directly from your application, we recommend that you use the AWS Software Development Kits (SDKs). The easy-to-use libraries in the AWS SDKs make it unnecessary to call the low-level DynamoDB API directly from your application. The libraries take care of request authentication, serialization, and connection management. For more information, go to [Using the AWS SDKs with DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/UsingAWSSDK.html) in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide.

I would recommend this approach rather than worrying about the ambiguity of class documentation.